# regex var extract without a dot

Tags: regex, string, filter

I have a string:

```
"{balba $aaa = $bbb.test == $ddd == $sdfsf.dfgdfg.dfg}"
```

I tried to create a regex that extract all vars without a dot.

Expected result is:

1. $aaa
2. $ddd

My regex is `\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^\.]` but it does not work.

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: +1 Johnsyweb. Regex do vary from environment to environment, so, correct Regex answers for other environments may not work for you. Please specify your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give the language, so here is a solution using a negative lookahead and a possessive quantifier (**NOTE: not supported by some flavours**).

```
\$\w++(?!\.)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vu8d)

`\w++` Match at least one word character and do not backtrack.

`(?!\.)` a negative lookahead that ensures that there is no `.` following

Comment: _Note to passersby_: if your regex engine doesn't support [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), you could have better luck using [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it in Python, using positive and negative [*lookahead assertions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=...)` and `(?!...)`):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '"{balba $aaa = $bbb.test == $ddd == $sdfsf.dfgdfg.dfg}"'
>>> for index, found in enumerate(re.findall('\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?!\.)(?=\W)', s)):
...     print '%d. %s' % (index + 1, found)
...
1. $aaa
2. $ddd
```

...where you assert that the identifier contains only the permitted characters followed by no dots and then a non-identifier character.

This could be simplified to:

```
>>> for index, found in enumerate(re.findall('\$\w+(?!\.)(?=\W)', s)):
...     print '%d. %s' % (index + 1, found)
...
1. $aaa
2. $ddd
```

Comment: This however only finds variable names followed by a space. What if there’s something else?

Comment: I'm just guessing since we don't have enough info to say, but if `($aaa $bbb)` or `{balba $aaa==$ddd}` are also legal strings, perhaps using a word boundary (e.g., `\$\w+\b(?!\.)`) could be desirable.